# Canopy density & NDVI Regression using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, ndvi, regression

I have a Landsat ETM+ image, I also have 200 sample points with coordinates,canopy density, different band values and NDVI values.

If I build OLS model I only got sample points regressed.

How can I join the image and the points so I can do regression and produce a map in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS I'll give you a blueprint to follow.

1. [Convert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WT2awFra5Gk) your sample points into a shapefile.
2. Project / [Reproject](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000024p000000) your shapefile to match your ETM+ image, mostly likely UTM but not always.
3. Use the [Sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002v000000) or [Extract multi-value to points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002s000000.htm) tool to bring the values from the ETM+ image to your shapefile.
4. Run the [OLS](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//005p00000022000000) in ArcGIS.
5. Render the shapefile with the OLS values. Usually some form of residual [map](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Interpreting_OLS_results).

Comment: Thanks for answering!This is how I did yesterday:1),exported all sample points by first ‘Display XY data’ and then ‘Export data’; 2),use "Sample" extracted all points from ETM+ image, then I got a table and exported it to a DBF file. 2), I copied all band values from DBF to original sample .xls file, calculated NDVI; 3), I also did linear regression in .xls, since I'm asked to apply the equation to the EMT+ image for mapping, I joined the .xls (with NDVI) to sample points shape file; 4), ran OLS, failed.

Comment: Between steps 3 & 4. Do not run 0LS on the joined data. Export to a new shapefile and run OLS on this new file.

Comment: still not working efter join→export....only got sample points regressed...

Comment: Got a PDF from my teacher, we have to use Image Analysis in ArcGIS to calculate NDVI for ETM+ image, then applying NDVI raster layer in regression equation in Map Algebra. I can produce the map now except it seems I got different Band values after 'Sample': I got NP_2_30513,14...17, I assumed they are band3,band4...band7 and used them calculated NDVI in Excel. Did I interpolate them wrong? Is that why my regression is different from my techer's?